# Select minimum value by value transition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with some data related to articles in a store:

```
Article     Date         Stored
A           22/08/2019   True
A           23/08/2019   True
A           24/08/2019   True
A           25/08/2019   False
A           26/08/2019   True
A           27/08/2019   True
A           28/08/2019   False
A           29/08/2019   False
A           30/08/2019   True
```

What I'd like to get is the minimum date where A has value Stored=True and value Stored=False:

```
Article     Date         Stored
A           22/08/2019   True
A           25/08/2019   False
```

But, let's suppose that, for article A, there is data where Stored=True after Stored=False (case of date 26/08/2019). In this situation, I'd like to show this minimum value too. To sum up, **what I want is the minimum date value each time that a transition happens (this is, Stored passes from True to False or from False to True)**:

So my final result would be this:

```
Article     Date         Stored
A           22/08/2019   True
A           25/08/2019   False
A           26/08/2019   True
A           28/08/2019   False
A           30/08/2019   True
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typical `gaps-and-islands` problem. You can use `row_number()` analytical function :

```
select article, min(date) as date, stored
  from (
        select *,
               row_number() over (partition by article, stored order by date) as rn1,
               row_number() over (partition by article order by date) as rn2
          from tab 
       ) t
 group by article, stored, rn1 - rn2
 order by date;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=72d6645256a83191416bb5b888ccd8e5)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think I came up with an answer:

```
select article,date,stored from(
select
article,date,stored,lag(stored) over (order by date) stored_previous_value from my_table
)q1
where stored!=stored_previous_value or stored_previous_value is null
```

Comment: [your solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=78231c3643234a0fa091e97896afc7ae) is also good.